cyclonedds 0.10.5 python subscription failed
I installed cyclonedds-0.10.5-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl on Windows 10. I can successfully subscribe and publish using the cyclonedds-python-0.10.5\examples\helloworld\helloworld.py demo in cyclonedds-python-0.10.5.tar.gz. However, I split it into two .py files: publisher.py and subscriber.py. Then I use publisher.py to publish and subscriber.py to subscribe, but it fails to subscribe. I opened the log in cyclonedds.xml, but it doesn't seem to show why. What's going on?
helloworld.py:
"""


* Copyright(c) 2021 ZettaScale Technology and others
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0, or the Eclipse Distribution License
 * v. 1.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
"""

from dataclasses import dataclass

from cyclonedds.domain import DomainParticipant
from cyclonedds.pub import DataWriter
from cyclonedds.sub import DataReader
from cyclonedds.topic import Topic

from cyclonedds.idl import IdlStruct


# Define a HelloWorld datatype with one member, data, with as type 'string'
# In IDL this would be defined as "struct HelloWorld { string data; };"
@dataclass
class HelloWorld(IdlStruct, typename="HelloWorld.Msg"):
    data: str


# Create a DomainParticipant, your entrypoint to DDS
# The default domain id is 0.
dp = DomainParticipant()

# Create a Topic with topic name "Hello" and as datatype "HelloWorld" structs.
tp = Topic(dp, "Hello", HelloWorld)

# Create a DataWriter that can send structs on the "Hello" topic
dw = DataWriter(dp, tp)

# Create a DataReader that can receive structs on the "Hello" topic
dr = DataReader(dp, tp)

# Create a HelloWorld sample and write it to the network
sample = HelloWorld(data='Hello, World!')
dw.write(sample)

# Read samples from the network and print the data in the first one
# This should print "Hello, World!"
sample = dr.read()[0]
print(sample.data)

publisher.py:
"""
 * Copyright(c) 2021 ZettaScale Technology and others
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0, or the Eclipse Distribution License
 * v. 1.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
"""
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass

from cyclonedds.domain import DomainParticipant
from cyclonedds.pub import DataWriter
from cyclonedds.sub import DataReader
from cyclonedds.topic import Topic

from cyclonedds.idl import IdlStruct


# Define a HelloWorld datatype with one member, data, with as type 'string'
# In IDL this would be defined as "struct HelloWorld { string data; };"
@dataclass
class HelloWorld(IdlStruct, typename="HelloWorld.Msg"):
    data: str


# Create a DomainParticipant, your entrypoint to DDS
# The default domain id is 0.

dp = DomainParticipant(0)

# Create a Topic with topic name "Hello" and as datatype "HelloWorld" structs.
tp = Topic(dp, "Hello", HelloWorld)

# Create a DataWriter that can send structs on the "Hello" topic
dw = DataWriter(dp, tp)

# Create a DataReader that can receive structs on the "Hello" topic
#dr = DataReader(dp, tp)

# Create a HelloWorld sample and write it to the network
while True:
    sample = HelloWorld(data='Hello, World!')
    try:
        dw.write(sample)
        print("write successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to write sample: {e}")
    time.sleep(0.5)  # 0.5 s

# Read samples from the network and print the data in the first one
# This should print "Hello, World!"
#sample = dr.read()[0]
#print(sample.data)

subscriber.py:
"""
 * Copyright(c) 2021 ZettaScale Technology and others
 *
 * This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
 * terms of the Eclipse Public License v. 2.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0, or the Eclipse Distribution License
 * v. 1.0 which is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0 OR BSD-3-Clause
"""

from dataclasses import dataclass

from cyclonedds.domain import DomainParticipant
from cyclonedds.pub import DataWriter
from cyclonedds.sub import DataReader
from cyclonedds.topic import Topic

from cyclonedds.idl import IdlStruct


# Define a HelloWorld datatype with one member, data, with as type 'string'
# In IDL this would be defined as "struct HelloWorld { string data; };"
@dataclass
class HelloWorld(IdlStruct, typename="HelloWorld.Msg"):
    data: str


# Create a DomainParticipant, your entrypoint to DDS
# The default domain id is 0.
dp = DomainParticipant(0)

# Create a Topic with topic name "Hello" and as datatype "HelloWorld" structs.
tp = Topic(dp, "Hello", HelloWorld)

# Create a DataWriter that can send structs on the "Hello" topic
#dw = DataWriter(dp, tp)

# Create a DataReader that can receive structs on the "Hello" topic
dr = DataReader(dp, tp)

# Create a HelloWorld sample and write it to the network
#sample = HelloWorld(data='Hello, World!')
#dw.write(sample)

# Read samples from the network and print the data in the first one
# This should print "Hello, World!"
print(dr.read())
sample = dr.read()[0]
print(sample.data)

cyclonedds.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain Id="any">
        <General>
            <Interfaces>
                <NetworkInterface autodetermine="true" priority="default" multicast="default" />
            </Interfaces>
            <AllowMulticast>default</AllowMulticast>
            <MaxMessageSize>65500B</MaxMessageSize>
        </General>
        <Discovery>
            <EnableTopicDiscoveryEndpoints>true</EnableTopicDiscoveryEndpoints>
        </Discovery>
        <Internal>
            <Watermarks>
                <WhcHigh>500kB</WhcHigh>
            </Watermarks>
        </Internal>
        <Tracing>
            <Category>fatal,error,warning,info</Category>
            <Verbosity>config</Verbosity>
            <OutputFile>D:\conda_dobot\cdds.log.${CYCLONEDDS_PID}</OutputFile>
        </Tracing>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

